# Blender animation navigating in a star system

Tags: animation, parent, navigation, empty

I'm working on a short film. The shot shows an holographic device, that display a star system. I want to navigate in this system, with the ability to zoom in and out to specific Point Of Interest (POI) like planets. The camera is fixed, and when I zoom to specific POI, I want it to be in the center of the device display.

[image]

Idea 1 is to create an empty, and make it parent of all the holographic objects. But after I keyframed the empty, the whole animation doesn't look good, especially when I zoom in to planet.

Idea 2 is to create a line where each vertex matches the POI locations, and then I would change my origin during the animation so I could transform, rotate and scale based on that origin (not working because I can't change the origin, and keep the previous locations).

I would like to know if someone has an idea on how to animate it so it looks like navigating in that system?

Here is a blockout of what I want to achieve, on some planets, it looks bad because the parent object scale go beyond 5000 units lol.

https://www.facebook.com/SamihElsakhawiCG/videos/957103476036298

Comment: By "zoom", I'm guessing you're talking about dolly shots ? What do you mean by "navigating", like a POV from a plane/spaceship ? Is the device on the bottom part always visible (and holograph is changing), or do you want the camera to dolly inside the holograph (holograph and device fixed in position) ?

Comment: Things like this are usually most easily accomplished by simply moving the camera (or snapping to alternate cameras) - is there some reason yours needs to be fixed (and not just give the impression of being fixed)?

Comment: I want to make this shot fix. The camera is not moving. It's just the holographic parts, like if someone is using it to navigate into different POI locations.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... in general it fails for circular dependences (logic loop) ... you want to place at location of specific object location that is based on parent location ... so probably some geo-node master with sim nodes.

---

If no one ... here is something, that is not probably what you asked exactly, but could be an acceptable fake that could work s for you ...

[image]

All colored objects are just a particles rendered as Collection emitted from Icosphere. Icosphere is using two Constraints ...

- **Child of** > *Target - Empty*
  (Empty is located in centre with rotation animation)
- **Copy Location** > *Target - Empty*
  (animate *Influence* value)

To make this work you have to position Origin of Icosphere (= the Emitter) at position of specific particle (object) you want to focus in your animation ... Torus in my case.

[image]